# SharePoint 2007 - Audience

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007, timer-jobs

We have scheduled to execute the Audience (all) compilation job and found that it is failed to complete with the below error:

'The audience cannot be compiled while another job in progress'

if we compile the audience manually, it is working perfectly without any issues.

Could be due to someother Timer jobs scheduled at that time? or What would be issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check the timer definitions for a previous audience compilation. Its trying to run a job that it already finds in the job definition.